# declare variable in assembly in Linux kernel?

Tags: assembly, linux-kernel, x86-64

i am new in assembly and in Linux kernel. i want to show 100 recently used for all processes.(`strace` just shows for one process.).
to do this i want to declare an array with 100 index in `arch/kernel/entry_64.s` then send it's memory address to C function of my system call and show them to user, but i can not declare array in assembly. how can i do it?

Comment: Learn to walk before you run. Starting out with hacking the linux kernel might not be the best idea. Anyway, you need to know what type of items you want to store in your array. You can do something like `array .space 100*item_size`. You will probably want to put it in a writable section too.

Comment: i just want to save system call numbers and add new system call to show 100 recently used system call. do you have better idea?

Comment: What do you need those for? How about `strace` ? PS: don't forget that you probably have multiple cores.

Comment: strace shows used system call for one process, but i want to show 100 recently used system call for all processes

Comment: How about system call auditing then?

Comment: please edit question as per your requirement.

Comment: this is a small part of my homework. i must show 100 recently used system call for all processes. i want to save system call id in entry_64.s. then send its memory address to C function of my system call then show them to user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't use auditing as-is, then I would suggest you tweak the auditing code path.

1) make the call unconditional,such as by inserting a `jmp auditsys` before `system_call_fastpath`
2) change `audit_syscall_entry` to your liking (that's C code in kernel/auditsc.c)

Comment: thanks for answer! if i declare an array in this file how can i access it in from my syscall C function?

Comment: Do you know C? Just declare it global, and use an `extern` in the other file. You could also just create your own audit function in the other file and change the assembly to call that instead of the original one.